# Which rack level of oven is suitable for baking choco lava cakes?

Tags: baking

I've always done baking and cooking in microwave ovens but I don't have any idea of the ovens installed under the cooktops..
Today I'm trying it first time..baking choco lava cakes (funfoods bake mix). 
On the pack it is mentioned-bake at 200 degrees for 15 mins.
There are four rack levels in the oven but I don't know in which one I should bake it.
Please help!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

When a recipe doesn't specify a rack level, try to place whatever you are baking in the middle. So, with 4 levels, you place it on the second (counted from bottom to top). It is the default for most things. Generally, a recipe will tell you if another level is needed.